# Writing Maven Plugin: How to replace Maven properties on reading an input file?

Tags: plugins, maven

I am writing a custom Maven plugin that is doing some custom stuff including calling Ant. The build.xml I'm going to use is always the same, therefore I add it as resource file in the plugin and read it from classpath during runtime. That is, it's NOT provided by the Maven project calling my plugin, but in the plugin itself.

This build.xml may contain Maven properties such as `${project.name}`, `${project.build.directory}` etc. which of course are those of the target Maven project. Hence, I have to replace all those properties in my input file by the real values before calling Ant.

How do I do that? I guess there must be a more convenient way than setting up the replacement table myself, since Maven is doing this property replacement all the time on all kind of files...

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Christoph.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Maven Ant Tasks](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/index.html) which should allow you to parse your pom, especially the [POM Task](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/examples/pom.html).

Comment: Well, this is actually not what I want to do... reading a POM from Ant build file. Instead, in my Maven plugin, I want to read an Ant build file from classpath and do some replacements in there, then write the result in a temporary file and call Ant (by maven-antrun-plugin) to execute the build file. All of this is working, but I currently have to replace all properties manually, one at a time. I thought there must be some utility functionality in Maven that helps...